# Image to byte[], Convert and ConvertBack

Tags: c#, image, windows-phone-7

I have a service that converts images stored on a website to byte array

```
                HttpWebRequest myRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("URLTOIMAGE");
                myRequest.Method = "GET";
                HttpWebResponse myResponse = (HttpWebResponse)myRequest.GetResponse();
                Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(myResponse.GetResponseStream());
                myResponse.Close();
                ms = new MemoryStream();
                bmp.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Bmp);
```

This code returns a byte array that I store in a database (SQL Azure). In my Windows Phone application, I try to convert this byte array to display it on my page.

```
public class BytesToImageConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        BitmapImage empImage = new BitmapImage();
        empImage.SetSource(new MemoryStream((Byte[])value));
        return empImage;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter,
                                System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

The byte array is well received by the application, but an exception is thrown when I try to do a SetSource.

```
empImage.SetSource(new MemoryStream((Byte[])value));
=> "Exception was unhandled", The request is not supported
```

Can you help me? Thx

Comment: what type of image are you trying to load?

Comment: It's JPEG => byte[] and byte[] to BitmapImage (for Imagesource)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code works :

```
public class BytesToImageConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream((Byte[])value);
        WriteableBitmap bmp = new WriteableBitmap(173, 173);
        bmp.LoadJpeg(stream);
        return bmp;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter,
                                System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Thank you everyone :)

Comment: you can also check the solution here that uses a more dynamic approach for the picture size: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9948252/byte-array-to-writeablebitmap-image-ivalueconverter-for-wp7/9949432#9949432

Answer (score 2):

these questions have already been answered on stackoverflow
for the image to a byte[] try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6597676)
and for the byte[] to image try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3335819)

Comment: I use the same code (use of memeorystream), but it does not work.

Answer (score 1):

```
private ImageSource GetPhoto(byte[] bytearr)
{
   if (bytearr != null)
   {
      BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage();

      InMemoryRandomAccessStream ms = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream();
      ms.AsStreamForWrite().Write(bytearr, 0, bytearr.Length);
      ms.Seek(0);

      image.SetSource(ms);
      ImageSource src = image;

      return src;
   }
   else
      return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For my UWP app i use the following IValueConverter to convert a byte array to a bindable object for an `<Image Source={Binding} />`

```
internal class ByteImageSourceConverter : IValueConverter
{
    object IValueConverter.Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        if (value == null)
            return null;
        return ByteToImage((byte[])value);
    }

    object IValueConverter.ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    static ImageSource ByteToImage(byte[] imageBytes)
    {
        BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage();
        image.SetSource(imageBytes.ConvertToInMemoryRandomAcessStream());
        ImageSource src = image;
        return src;
    }
}

internal static InMemoryRandomAccessStream ConvertToInMemoryRandomAcessStream(this byte[] arr)
{
    var randomAccessStream = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream();
    randomAccessStream.WriteAsync(arr.AsBuffer());
    randomAccessStream.Seek(0);
    return randomAccessStream;
}
```

Excuse me for the WriteAsync in a synchronous function. For the purpose of this post I don't have the time to solve this one, but it works this way :)