# Converting byte[] to image Windows Phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I have a little problem when I want to "create" image from byte array to image.Source (XAML)...
Firs I save byte array from web

```
string pomocna = responseS.GetValue("slika").ToString();
            byte[] pomocnoPolje = new byte[pomocna.Length];
            int brojac = 0;
            foreach (char a in pomocna)
            {
                pomocnoPolje[brojac] = byte.Parse(a.ToString());
                brojac++;
            }
            nova.slika = pomocnoPolje;
```

and then I set image source

```
stranica.slika.Source = ConvertToBitmapImage(nova.slika)
```

The problem occur on my ConvertToBitmapImage method

```
public static BitmapImage ConvertToBitmapImage(byte[] image)
    {
        var bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
        var memoryStream = new MemoryStream(image);
        bitmapImage.SetSource(memoryStream);
        return bitmapImage;
    }
```

on the line

```
bitmapImage.SetSource(memoryStream);
```

does anyone knows how to fix it?
thanks ahead

Comment: You need to use WriteableBitmap, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9948252/byte-array-to-writeablebitmap-image-ivalueconverter-for-wp7

Comment: What's the issue you're having with that line?

Comment: Syste.Exception: The component cannot be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x88982F50) at MS.Internal.Xcplmports.CheckHResult(UInt32 hr) at MS.Internal.Xcplmports.BitmapSource_SetSource(BitmapSource bitmapSource, CValue& byteStream) at ...etcetera... if that means anything to you

Answer (score 0):

If your `byte[] image` is a JPEG and you want to keep the memory stream do something like this:

```
public static BitmapImage ConvertToBitmapImage(byte[] image)
{
    WriteableBitmap wb = null;

    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(image))
    {
        try
        {
            wb = Microsoft.Phone.PictureDecoder.DecodeJpeg(ms);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string error_message = ex.Message;
        }
    }

    return ConvertWBtoBI(wb);
}

// converts a WriteableBitmap to a BitmapImage
private BitmapImage ConvertWBtoBI(WriteableBitmap wb)
{
    if(wb == null)
       return null;

    BitmapImage bi;

    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        wb.SaveJpeg(ms, wb.PixelWidth, wb.PixelHeight, 0, 100);
        bi = new BitmapImage();
        bi.SetSource(ms);
    }

    return bi;
}
```