# How to convert Image.Source to byte array?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

My WP7 app has an Image control whose Source is set in XAML to an image with its Build Action set to Content:

```
<Image x:Name="MyImage" Source="/Images/myimage.png"/>
```

I need to store this image in my SqlCe database as a byte array. This is my current code to convert to byte[]:

```
public byte[] ImageToArray() {
    BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage();
    image.CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.None;
    image.UriSource = new Uri( "/Images/myimage.png", UriKind.Relative );
    WriteableBitmap wbmp = new WriteableBitmap( image );
    return wbmp.ToArray();
}
```

The byte array saves to the database, but when I retrieve and my converter tries to convert it back (on a different page), I get "unspecified error." This is my converter:

```
public class BytesToImageConverter : IValueConverter {
    public object Convert( object Value, Type TargetType, object Parameter, CultureInfo Culture ) {
        if( Value != null && Value is byte[] ) {
            byte[] bytes = Value as byte[];

            using( MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream( bytes ) ) {
                stream.Seek( 0, SeekOrigin.Begin );

                BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage();
                image.SetSource( stream ); // Unspecified error here
                return image;
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

    public object ConvertBack( object Value, Type TargetType, object Parameter, CultureInfo Culture ) {
        throw new NotImplementedException( "This converter only works for one way binding." );
    }
}
```

I've done quite a bit of searching. As far as the converter, my code is pretty standard. I've seen mention that `stream.Position = 0;` is necessary, but my understanding is `stream.Seek` is doing the same thing; I've tried both.

As my converter is the same I've used in about a dozen projects now, I'm fairly convinced the problem lies in converting the Image control's Source to a byte array and thus my image data is corrupted. In the code above I'm hard coding the Uri, but I've also tried

```
BitmapImage image = MyImage.Source as BitmapImage;
```

without luck. I've been at this for hours and at my wit's end. What am I missing?

Comment: This question is already ask [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9806332). Must see

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the problem is in your `ImageToArray()` method. You are converting your `WriteableBitmap` object to array, but not the image itself. Try by replacing your method with the following:

```
    public byte[] ImageToArray()
    {
        BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage();
        image.CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.None;
        image.UriSource = new Uri("/Images/myimage.png", UriKind.Relative);
        WriteableBitmap wbmp = new WriteableBitmap(image);
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        wbmp.SaveJpeg(ms, wbmp.PixelWidth, wbmp.PixelHeight, 0, 100);
        return ms.ToArray();
    }
```

This methd writes the image to a stream as jpg, and returns it bytes. I haven't tried the code, but you shouldn't have problem to convert it back to a `BitmapImage` using your converter.

Comment: I've been using my code for over a year with several published apps, but dang if your code didn't fix it. Looks like I'll need to reevaluate what I've been doing. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The byte[] from image.UriSource may be base64 radix.You can browse byte[] or data in the SQL tale.
If radix is wrong,can not reverse to stream from byte[].So if radix is 64,must convert to 16 radix.