# Generate Imagesource with ZXing.Net.Mobile in UWP

Tags: c#, uwp, zxing

### Problem

I'm trying using ZXing.Net.Mobile to create barcode image in UWP project.
I found [this approach](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/WindowsPhone-81-Generate-ffe86c8a).

But in line `var wb = result.ToBitmap() as WriteableBitmap;` I'm getting result as byte[], which doesn't have method `ToBitmap()`.

Then I found this straight forward code

```
var writer = new BarcodeWriter();
writer.Format = BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE;
var wb = writer.Write("12345678");
BarcodeImg.Source = wb;
```

but last lane throws error `byte[] cannot be converted to ImageSource`

In my naive mind I thought "Ok that should be easy". HA! Everywhere I look I find something similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22066175/989631).

`BitmapImage` doesn't have methods `BeginInit` and `EndInit`.

### Question

How I can convert byte[] to ImageSource or use ZXing to create one?

I'm stuck, again I'm not familiar with UPW. I'll be thankful for each tip.

### Update

Ok at this moment situtation looks like this

```
private async void updateBarcodeImg(string code) {
    var writer = new BarcodeWriter();
    writer.Format = BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE;
    var wb = writer.Write(code) as Byte[];
    try {
        BarcodeImg.Source = await ImageFromBytes(wb);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Debug.WriteLine(e.Message);
    }
}

public async static Task<BitmapImage> ImageFromBytes(Byte[] bytes) {
    BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage();
    using (IRandomAccessStream stream = bytes.AsBuffer().AsStream().AsRandomAccessStream()) {
        stream.Seek(0);
        await image.SetSourceAsync(stream);
    }
    return image;
}
```

### Update

And in line `await image.SetSourceAsync(stream);` an exception is throwing "Exception from HRESULT: 0x88982F50". Google says that this is because stream is not set to position 0. But I do it a one line earlier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to your question, you are going to use [**ZXing.Net.Mobile**](https://github.com/Redth/ZXing.Net.Mobile) to create barcode image. However [the sample](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/WindowsPhone-81-Generate-ffe86c8a) you've found is using [**ZXing.Net**](http://zxingnet.codeplex.com/). They are not the same library.

To use **ZXing.Net.Mobile**, we need install [ZXing.Net.Mobile from NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ZXing.Net.Mobile):

```
Install-Package ZXing.Net.Mobile
```

And then use following code:

```
var writer = new ZXing.Mobile.BarcodeWriter
{
    Format = ZXing.BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE,
    Options = new ZXing.Common.EncodingOptions
    {
        Height = 300,
        Width = 300
    },
    Renderer = new ZXing.Mobile.WriteableBitmapRenderer() { Foreground = Windows.UI.Colors.Black }
};
var writeableBitmap = writer.Write("https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-apps");

QrCodeImg.Source = writeableBitmap;
```

Also we can use **ZXing.Net** by install [ZXing.Net from NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ZXing.Net/):

```
Install-Package ZXing.Net
```

And use the code in the sample:

```
ZXing.IBarcodeWriter writer = new ZXing.BarcodeWriter
{
    Format = ZXing.BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE,//Mentioning type of bar code generation
    Options = new ZXing.Common.EncodingOptions
    {
        Height = 300,
        Width = 300
    },
    Renderer = new ZXing.Rendering.PixelDataRenderer() { Foreground = Windows.UI.Colors.Black }//Adding color QR code
};
var result = writer.Write("http://www.bsubramanyamraju.blogspot.com ");
var wb = result.ToBitmap() as Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging.WriteableBitmap;
//Displaying QRCode Image
QrCodeImg.Source = wb;
```

Please note that we **can not** use these two libraries at **the same time**. Please make sure you are using the right code that matches the library you've chosen.

Comment: OMG.. thanks! ZXing.Net.Mobile variant is working like charm.